# Sending a bash command to another script as a string instead of executing it

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I'm trying to write a script which will modify and run another script.  Every time I try to use sed to replace a command line in my other script, the command actually executes instead of being sent into the other script as a string.  Below is a minimum working example.  I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  I want to just run script 1, which will then run script 2 a few times.  Thanks!

Script 1:

```
#!/bin/bash

./script2.sh
./script2.sh
./script2.sh

lineNo=3
var2=(var=$(( RANDOM % 399 )))
sed -i "${lineNo}s/.*/"${var2[@]}"/" script2.sh

./script2.sh
./script2.sh
./script2.sh
```

Script 2:

```
#!/bin/bash

var=$(( RANDOM % 199 )) #This line should be replaced with "var=$(( RANDOM % 399 ))" but instead is getting replaced with "var=90" (or some other random number).  i.e. the command is executing.

<... Do stuff with random number stored in $var...>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elliot's answer prodded me in the right direction.

Script 1 needed single quotes around the command I was trying to send into the other script:

```
#!/bin/bash

lineNo=3
var2='var=$(( RANDOM % 399 ))'
sed -i "${lineNo}s/.*/$var2/" script2.sh
```

now the command enters script2 instead of being executed along the way.

Answer (score 2):

Embed the string in single quotes.

```
var='$(( RANDOM % 199 ))'
```

Comment: The problem isn't that the RANDOM line wasn't executing, The problem is that it WAS getting executing.  I wanted it to go in as a string instead of getting executed.  Maybe I didn't make it clear